# Как написать свои собственные getchar(), gets(), putchar(), puts() без использования stdio.h на Си?

Tags: c

Изучаю Си через книгу Дейтела, дошел до задания где нужно писать свои собственные функции. И немного завис, гуглил, но что то мало инфы про написания своих собственных. Там прям все функции просят написать, начиная от работой со строкой и сомволами и дальше...

Comment: Пользоваться API операционной системы...

Comment: Под какую операционную систему?

Comment: Win10 ......................................

Comment: спасибо, буду сейчас копаться в что такое API

Comment: @rtn2020, посмотрите [вот этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28890482/8086115) ответ, это то, что вам нужно.

Comment: @eanmos Спасибо, сейчас гляну!

Comment: Вообще-то неужели где-то такое задание в книге может быть? Это ж, как бы выразиться... совсем не для начинающих. Вы точно правильно поняли задание?

Comment: @harry мне теперь тоже так кажется... Тема API довольно обширная, мягко говоря. Сейчас я прохожу сами функции для работ со строками, символами такие как strptr(), puts() и т.д. Меня просят написать свои собственные варианты данных функций. Вот думаю теперь как это реализовать

Comment: Ну, `puts` - я думаю, циклически вызывая `putchar`, `strptr` - такой стандартной функции я вообще не знаю... Что за издание книги, + страницы? попробую найти в интернете и посмотреть, что там хотят *на самом деле*. Не [эта](ftp://ftp.micronet-rostov.ru/linux-support/books/programming/C/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%20-%20%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%A1%D0%B8.PDF) случайно?

Comment: @Harry она самая) Вот ссылка https://yadi.sk/i/7b_TAup9kLgOXQ 21 страница 8.29 задание. Там говориться см рисунок но на нем лишь сам список фунций. СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ !!!

Comment: Мда. `gets` и `puts` понятно - просто через циклы, но `getchar` и `putchar`? что-то странно...

Comment: Нашел оригинал - нет, переведено верно (правда, уже `gets` не просят реализовывать :) - ее же уже в стандарте нет). Если они и в самом деле хотят реализации чтения на низком уровне... ну не верю :(

Comment: @Harry рад что такие люди есть как вы) Ну надо же, для незнакомого человека на такое пойти) теперь я могу спать сегодня спокойно зная что не сделанное мной задание было слишком замудренным) Правда все же осадок желания изучить API есть) Бесконечной энергии и спасибо вам!

Comment: @Harry, дык `fgetc()`/`fputc()` же при этом вроде как не запрещено использовать...

Comment: "Язык программирования С" Б.Керниган Д.Ритчи
Здесь, по-моему, расписывают все функции стандартной библиотеки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле, здесь, как говорится, возможны варианты... :-)

1. MS DOS - задача решается элементарно путём вызова 21-го прерывания с кодом 01. (http://www.codenet.ru/progr/dos/dos_0009.php).
2. GUI программа под современными ОС типа Windows/Linux/Mac - тоже элементарно. Пишем обработчик события "KeyPressed" и выбираем символ из дескриптора события.
3. Самый сложный вариант - консольная программа под управлением ОС с GUI. Здесь всё определяется спецификой конкретной ОС и общего решения нет. По любому - довольно сложно... Именно этот вариант и рассматривался большинством комментаторов.